# How to set coordinates as a state space (range) for use in Q-table?

Tags: python, machine-learning, coordinates, q-learning, state-space

Suppose I have a class Player that i want to use as my agent.I want all the coordinates possible in my environment to be my state space In my environment, I want to use the coordinates of the player as my state.How should I go about setting my "stateSpace/ range" then?

```
self.stateSpaceX = a for a in range(int(GRIDWIDTH)))
self.stateSpaceY = b for b in range(int(GRIDHEIGHT)))
self.stateSpace = ???
```

Comment: There are many answers to this questions. For instance, you could simply use the coordinates as your state. If you want an integer, you can use `y * GRIDWIDTH + x`.

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci sorry I think I confused myself, it should be state space, not state. If so, how should i go about doing it then?

Comment: If you're using tuples it would be [|0; GRIDWIDTH - 1|] x [|0; GRIDHEIGHT - 1|]. For integers it would be [|0; GRIDWIDTH * GRIDHEIGHT - 1|]

Comment: Erm @ThomasSchillaci sorry for disturbing you again but my IDE (atom) doesnt seem to recognise ; as valid syntax, and I had to replace the modulus with the function abs(). Could you advice me as to how to change it? I plan on using tuples, but x is invalid as well. Should I use * instead? But it tells me i cant multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: I wrote the mathematical representation of your state space, not the python implementation

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution:

```
from itertools import product

initstate = 0
StateSpace = {coord: initstate for coord in product(range(int(GRIDWIDTH)), range(int(GRIDHEIGHT)))}
```